# Area routing breaks in MVC6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In previous versions of ASP.NET, and using MVC 5, I could set up a route like this in my AreaRegistraion:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "pfrecent",
    "Forums/Recent/{page}",
    new { controller = ForumController.Name, action = "Recent", page = 1 },
    new[] { "PopForums.Controllers" });
```

This would route `/Forums/Recent` to the forum controller and its recent action. However, I can't figure out how to make it work in ASP.Net 5/MVC 6. I've added `[Area("Forums")]` to the controller class, and used this route from the Startup class:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "pfrecent",
    "Forums/Recent/{page}",
    new { controller = ForumController.Name, action = "Recent", page = 1 });
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "areaRoute",
    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

However, it resolves to `/Forums/Forum/Recent?page=1`. The intention is to continue using `/Forums/Recent`.

Comment: I'm confused...what do you mean by `it resolves to`...when you make a request like `/forums/recent`, is it no hitting the `forums` controller?...do you have any attribute routes decorated on the forums controller? if yes, remove them and try again

Comment: I mean /forums/recent returns 404, and the UrlHelpers only resolve to /forums/forum/recent?page=1. There are no routing attributes on the controller. Again, this is a straight port, known to work in MVC5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate answering my own questions, but after getting back to this, and looking at source and experimenting, I found that you have to specify the area in the route mapping, as well as the HtmlHelpers (I'm assuming this will be true for tag helpers as well, but I haven't gone that far yet in conversion.) So the route mapping has to look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "pfrecent",
    "Forums/Recent/{page?}",
    new { controller = ForumController.Name, action = "Recent", page = 1, Area = "Forums" }
);
```

The important part is the Area property in the route value object. The HtmlHelper has to look like this, also naming the Area:

```
@Html.ActionLink(PopForums.Resources.Recent, "Recent", ForumController.Name, new { page = 1, Area = "Forums" }, null)
```

It causes the URL for the recent page to be `/Forums/Recent` as expected. As best I can tell, setting routes in a derived `AreaRegistration` class in MVC5 set the area value on the routes for you. Having `[Area("Forums")]` on your controller class (which I already had) seems to assume the previous role of area registration.

Answer (score 4):

We are using this for enabling areas in MVC 6:

```
        // Configure MVC routing
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            // Areas support
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areaRoute",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            // Default routing
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

The first route is for areas, second is for main content.

Answer (score 4):

On Startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Business",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        })
```

on Controller

```
[Area("Business")]
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your Startup.cs file at the TOP of the routes list:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "forumsAreaRoute",
                template: "Forums/{action}/{page?}",
                defaults: new {area = "Forums", controller = "Forum", action = "Recent", page = 1});
```

Your Forum controller should look like this:

```
[Area("Forums")]
public class ForumController : Controller
{
    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Recent(int? page)
    {
        // Do action stuff here
    }
}
```

This solution will satisfy a url of http://somedomain.com/Forums/Recent/1 and return the first page.

Comment: I'm not looking for the catch all route on the area... I'm trying to do a specific route for /Forums/Recent to point to the Recent action on the Forum controller. Again, this worked as intended in MVC5.

Comment: Specific routes, especially that follow the default pattern should be avoided. This isn't a "catch all" route in the manner you speak of.  MVC will evaluate each portion of the URL for matching controller and action combinations. The "Home" controller and "Index" actions are the default if no other matching controller/action combinations are found.

In your example, it's clear you aren't actually using areas, so we can eliminate that portion altogether. I will edit my answer to provide the strict route you're looking for, though best practice is not to do so.

Comment: I *am* using areas. I can make the route work outside of an area just fine. It also worked as intended in MVC5. This isn't the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Alright, I'll take one more stab at this. From what you've explained, you have an area named "Forums" and a controller within that area called "Forum" and an action named "Recent" that accepts a page number.  
You apparently want to use http://somedomain/Forums/Recent/Page, which basically bypasses the "controller" portion of the path (Forum) and uses the area name only.  This can be done. I will amend my answer to satisfy this scenario. If you're trying to accomplish something different, you may need to amend your question as it's not clear and this may be why you're not getting answer.

Comment: That's still not what I'm looking for. I don't want to default to recent, I want the specific path to match, as it did before.